# How to Create annotations which can declare variable using class name from its usage

Tags: java, slf4j, spring-annotations, java-annotations

following

```
public class Testclass {

    private static final LogExtension log = new LogExtension(Testclass.class);

}
```

should work with just:

```
@LogExtension
public class Testclass{}
```

similar to @Slf4j with its annotation it creates an object like in all the classes where it is used.

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger internalLog = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExtension.class);
```

any help will be much appreciated.. thanks for reading. couldn't find much on the internet about how to do it.

I'm trying to create a annotation like

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@interface LogExt{ 
    LogExtension log() default new LogExtension(); 
}
```

but how to get the class type as default to create object of LogExtension ? to make it work like :

```
    private static final LogExtension log = new LogExtension(Testclass.class);
```

Scenario:
I'm trying to have a Logger class that can replace SLF4j as per my problem so it Like I want to create a custom annotation like @LogExtension similar to @slf4j which can execute on compile-time to produce

Comment: What is the reason for you wanting to do this?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  I want this class to be used by everyone, basically, they should be able to use it just by replacing `@Slf4j` with `@LogExtension` just that.

Comment: But why not just keep @slf4j?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, `LogExtension` is kind of a class that processes logs from only a few classes. I cant make it an appender coz I don't want all the logs over there. so I'm trying to solve this with the above approach.

Comment: Then first do a "how do I write an annotation processor" tutorial or two, and then have a very close look at how the @slf4j annotation does its job.  Any reason you just don't want to write the line out by hand yourself?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen `new LogExtension(Testclass.class);` basically how to get the class automatically in arguments, couldn't understand how slf4j is doing that.

Comment: You have the source.  Have a closer look.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen maybe I'm not getting your point .. what I found is `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Slf4j {
 /** @return The category of the constructed Logger. By default, it will use the type where the annotation is placed. */
 String topic() default "";
}`     and how I'm creating is  `@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@interface LogExt{
    LogExtension log() default new LogExtension();
}`   not sure how to pass the argument here with the class name where the annotation is used.